# Learning job functions on your own time worth it?

Tags: new-job, training

I was recently hired for a IT position but I haven't used SQL for 8 years since college.  Is it worth it to learn it on your own time so as to not take too long to start being productive at work or am I trying too hard?  I don't want to be stuck in training/learning for too long and look bad and maybe even let go.

Comment: This will probably closed as we cannot make choices for you. You seem to know the advantages and disadvantages, we cannot decide whether it's "worth it" for you.

Comment: It depends on how valuable the job function might be.  Typically learning provides you with more flexibility in future situations; so, there is some benefit.  However, not all learning is as valuable as some learning; and, it's very hard to predict the future.  If you have the time, I'd say go ahead and do it, for the items you think could be valuable in your next jobs.  None of us have a device to know the future; but, having mastered something makes you more attractive to future employers, if they value the thing you've mastered.

Comment: As a general rule if I think the skill is general enough to be used in my nexts jobs I'll study it on my own. If it's a specific skill that is only usefull in their legacy system, I may not be so motivated.

Comment: the answer here is a firm "Yes"

Answer (score 3):

Refreshing your skills is a good thing, especially if you want to be seen as a competent employee. 8 years is a long long time in the IT industry.

Comment: I've 3 times that amount of time (almost 4 time).  Yes, I've refreshed skill set many times; but, 8 years doesn't mean obsolete.  I'm still working, and still doing cutting edge stuff.  It's all about moving with the market.  When a person stops doing that, they become the person in a field that is (usually) shrinking.

Comment: @EdwinBuck I never meant obsolete, , just refresh. I'm old, but still keeping up with things.